# Can I use other database instead of firebase for Homegraph api?

Tags: google-smart-home

I am referencing to the smart-home-nodejs git repository on Actions On Google. This template provides an end to end example of how the smart-home app can be use. However, instead of using firebase, can I use my own database that host my devices and I would want to just call the Homegraph api to sync. Would this be possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the implementation of your backend can be designed however you want. You also are not restricted to using Cloud Functions or App Engine. While the end-to-end sample provides one example of how to do it, your backend just has to [implement a webhook and respond to intents](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/process-intents) plus have support to do things like [report state](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/report-state).

The [API reference](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/sync) contains all the information you needed to build a custom implementation.